# Excel and pgSQL

Tags: linux, excel, postgresql

How do I import data from a excel sheet onto a PGSQL database on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to export the data from Excel, to a CSV by using the `SAVE AS` functionality. Then use psql's native `\COPY` feature. You can find more information about it by using the command `\? COPY` in psql, or by visiting [the docs on COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html).

Comment: +1 Be prepared to deal with formats-datatypes issues, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (a bit of a workaround, but should work) is to import the Excel file into Access and then upping the resulting table into PostgreSQL over an ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this on a regular basis, then you should look into [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) - I've found it pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time and use Navicat[1] (about $79). You'll need a windows box to run the client as the linux client can't import from Excel.

You can import almost any data format (Access, Excel, DBF, Lotus ...), define a mapping between the source and destination which can be saved.

BTW I don't work for Navicat! Just I've tried a few DBA clients and this was by far the best for data imports.

[1] http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_pgsql/pgsql_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<?php

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=your_db user=postgres password=your_paswrd");
//call excel reader
require "excel_reader.php";
//press button
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $target = basename($_FILES['fopenl']['name']) ;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fopenl']['tmp_name'], $target);   
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_FILES['fopenl']['name'],false);   
//count row of excel xls
    $baris = $data->rowcount($sheet_index=0);    
//empty database before
    $drop = isset( $_POST["drop"] ) ? $_POST["drop"] : 0 ;
    if($drop == 1){
//empty employee table
             $truncate ="TRUNCATE TABLE employee";
             pgsql_query($truncate);
    };    
//import data from xls
    for ($i=1; $i<=$baris; $i++)
    {
//read from xls
      $emp_id = $data->val($i, 1);
      $date = $data->val($i, 2);
      $id_mac = $data->val ($i, 3);
      $val_a = $data->val($i, 4);
      $val_b = $data->val($i, 5);
      $stat = $data->val($i, 6);
      $note = $data->val ($i, 7);
//setelah data dibaca, masukkan ke tabel dari_finger
      $query_insert = "INSERT into employee (emp_id,date,id_mac,val_a,val_b,stat,note)values('$emp_id','$date','$id_mac','$val_a','$val_b','$stat','$note')";
//eksekusi query insert
      $insert = pg_query($query_insert);
    }    
  if(!$insert){
//jika import gagal
          die(pgsql_error());
      }else{
//jika impor berhasil
          echo " Data imported,";
    }
```